# Chinese characters not displayed using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, fonts, itext

I've been using itextsharp to generate pdf from my database data. My database data contains the text, the x and y coordinate and the page number. Here's how I do it.

```
 string oldFile = Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/App_Data/Documents/Templates/{0}", documentModel.Filename));

        // open the reader
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);
        Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
        iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(size);

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, _memoryStream);
        writer.CloseStream = false;
        document.Open();

        PdfContentByte cb;
        PdfImportedPage page;
        BaseFont bf;


foreach (var pageNumber in pages)
        {
            document.NewPage();

            cb = writer.DirectContent;
            // create the new page and add it to the pdf
            page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNumber);
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
            cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 9);

            var items = documentModel.FieldContents.Where(a => a.Page == pageNumber).ToList();

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                cb.BeginText();
                cb.ShowTextAligned(item.Alignment, item.Text ?? string.Empty, item.X, item.Y, item.Rotation);
                cb.EndText();
            }

        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        document.Close();
        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();

        byte[] byteInfo = _memoryStream.ToArray();
        _memoryStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
        _memoryStream.Position = 0;

        RedirectToAction("Index");
        return new FileStreamResult(_memoryStream, "application/pdf");
```

I've been using this for a while now. But I want to support chinese characters also. I tried inputting chinese characters, but it is not being displayed. I changed it back to english characters and it works. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You use `HELVETICA`, one of the standard 14 fonts, and you use `CP1252` encoding. Neither does the former include Chinese characters nor can Chinese characters be found on code page 1252. Thus, use a font which contains the required Chinese characters and use an encoding allowing these characters.

Comment: Thank you for the great suggestion. If you have set this as an answer I could have accepted it. Great tip. Thanks!

Comment: Simply accept Bruno's answer which illuminates these aspects some more.

Answer (score 2):

There are different errors in your code.

As mkl already explained, the Type 1 Helvetica font you're using isn't embedded and doesn't know anything about Chinese glyphs. You need to use a font that knows how to draw Chinese characters. Furthermore [CP1252 is the encoding for the Latin alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), so you shouldn't expect it to know anything about Chinese.

You're also creating code that is illegal (and that results in invalid PDF syntax):

```
cb.BeginText();
cb.ShowTextAligned(...);
cb.EndText();
```

This is a text object for which no font and size is defined. You are using the ´setFontAndSize()´ method in *graphics state* (where it doesn't belong) instead of in *text state* (where it's required). The fact that this code runs, tells me that you're using an old iTextSharp version. [You should upgrade.](http://lowagie.com/why5)

The solution to your problem is to find examples about adding [Chinese text with iText](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=395). Then create a ´Phrase´ and position it using [`ColumnText.showTextAligned();`](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=60). By using `ColumnText`, you avoid the problem you now experience with the low-level approach: you're using `beginText()` and `endText()` without reading the PDF specification. `ColumnText` will do all this difficult work under the hood.

In case the Java examples confuse you, please visit [this page](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/178) where you'll find links to the C# port of the corresponding examples.

Comment: I have fixed my problem by including a .ttf file with unicode and reference to it. The code works without any syntax error code.

Answer (score 1):

You can load you local Chinese font like this

```
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(
                "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\simhei.ttf",
                BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,
                BaseFont.EMBEDDED); 
Font font = new Font(baseFont);
```

And then use the "font" for further texting. 
And you can reference the common used Chinese local fonts as below

```
            {"yahei", "C:\\WINDOWS\\FONTS\\msyh.ttf"},
            {"fangsong", "C:\\WINDOWS\\FONTS\\simfang.ttf"},
            {"heiti" ,"C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\simhei.ttf"},
            {"kaiti" ,"C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\simkai.ttf"},
            {"lishu" ,"C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\SIMLI.TTF"},
            {"youyuan" ,"C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\SIMYOU.TTF"},
            {"songti" ,"C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\simsun.ttc,0"},
            {"xinsongti" ,"C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\simsun.ttc,1"}
```

Hope it helps you!